# Customizing BarLegend for Missing[ ] data

Tags: plotting, color, legending

My apologies if something similar has been asked, I could not find a question on the same issue. I have created the following colour map (heat map) using a toy sample with `RandomReal`.

```
s = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {80, 50}];

ListDensityPlot[s, Mesh -> Automatic, Mesh -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", FrameLabel -> {Number, Year}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{{0, "Y1"}, {20, "Y2"}, {40, "Y3"}, {60, "Y4"}, {80,
        "Y5"}}, 
     None}, {{{1, "One"}, {10, "Two"}, {20, "Three"}, {30, 
       "Four"}, {40, "Five"}, {50, "Six"}}, None}}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Heat Map", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}] /. 
 x : (FrameTicks -> _) :> (x /. s_String :> Rotate[s, 45 Degree])
```

However, I may have missing observations on the map. If I fill the gaps with 0,they will appear green. If they are left balnk, the spaces will look white. Is it possible to set all values equal to 0 being coloured with something that is not in the palette (legend), e.g. black or grey?

The issue is one of presentation, since with my actual data a part of the map is missing and I would like to see if it having white or a different colour would make it look better.

On a side note, if you have a better colour palette or idea on how to visualise more-or-less random looking data, please be my guest.

Comment: What are the gaps You are mentioning? Data array is full of numbers which none of are 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A data set with missing observations:

```
SeedRandom[1];
s = Map[If[Abs[#] < 10^-1, Missing[], #] &, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {80, 50}], {-1}];
```

#### Update:

In general, since non-numeric / missing data do not lie in the numeric range of plotted values, a more accurate legend would be a combination of `BarLegend` showing numerical values depicted in the plot and a seperate legend showing the color used for rendering non-numeric/missing values.

A simple way to achieve this is to combine a `BarLegend` with a `SwatchLegend` showing the label and color used to render missing/non-numeric values:

```
ListDensityPlot[s, Mesh -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> Column[
   {BarLegend["Rainbow", Frame -> False, LegendMargins -> 0], 
    SwatchLegend[{White}, {"Missing[]"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 14]}]]
```

[image]

The custom legend `barLegendWithMissingValues` below adds a rectangle with desired color/label/size for missing values below a  regular `BarLegend`:

```
ClearAll[barLegendWithMissingValues]

barLegendWithMissingValues[label_ : Automatic, color_ : Automatic,  
   size_ : 30, gap_ : 3, offset_ : 10] := 
 Module[{coord = First@Cases[ToBoxes@#, RasterBox[_, a_, ___] :> First@a, All]},
   With[{txt = {label /. Automatic -> "Missing[]" /. Style -> StyleBox, 
        Offset[{offset, 0}, coord {-1, 1} - {0, gap + size/2}], Left},
     clr = color /. Automatic -> LightGray,
     rct = {#, # {-1, 1} + {0, size}} &@(coord - {0, size + gap}),
     ef = EdgeForm[Directive[AbsoluteThickness[.5], RGBColor[.5, .5, .5]]]},
    RawBoxes @ Replace[ToBoxes @ #,
      {a___, r_RasterBox, b___} :> RuleCondition @
        {a, r, InsetBox @@ txt, clr, ef, RectangleBox @@ rct, b}, All]]] &
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[{barLegendWithMissingValues[] @ BarLegend["Rainbow"],
  barLegendWithMissingValues[Style["NaN", 12], Brown, 50, 5]@
     BarLegend["Rainbow", LabelStyle -> 14],
  barLegendWithMissingValues[Style["NaN", 12], Black, 40, 15]@
     BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {-5, 15}}, LabelStyle -> 14, 
       LegendMarkerSize -> {90, 300}]}, Spacer[30]]
```

[image]

```
ReplaceAll[b_BarLegend :> barLegendWithMissingValues[Automatic, White]@b]@
 ListDensityPlot[s, Mesh -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
ReplaceAll[b_BarLegend :> barLegendWithMissingValues[] @ b] @
 ListDensityPlot[s, Mesh -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", BoundaryStyle -> White, 
  Prolog -> {LightGray, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

#### Original answer:

`ListDensityPlot` excludes (renders as White) areas where data is non-real. So we need to modify the `BarLegend` to show the color used for excluded areas. This can be done using the (undocumented) option `StyledContours` (or `"StyledContours"`) and adding the associated tick label using the (also undocumented) option `Ticks` (`"Ticks"` also works) in `BarLegend`:

```
ListDensityPlot[s, Mesh -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, 
   StyledContours -> {{0, Directive[Thick, White]}}, 
   Ticks -> (Range[-1, 1, .5] /. 0. -> {0, Missing[]})]]
```

[image]

We can set the color of excluded areas using `Prolog` and use the same color for styled contours in `BarLegend`:

```
ListDensityPlot[s, Mesh -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 BoundaryStyle -> White, 
 Prolog -> {LightGray, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}, 
 PlotLegends ->  BarLegend[Automatic, 
    "StyledContours" -> {{0, Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], LightGray]}}, 
    "Ticks" -> (Range[-1, 1, .5] /. 0. -> {0, Missing[]})]]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I accepted this as answer since it does not include a custom function and did teach me something about undocumented options, which I can use in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[1];
s = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {80, 50}];
Clear[cf]
cf[x_] := Blend[ReplacePart[
    ColorData["Rainbow"][#] & /@ Range[0, 1, 1/30]
    , {{15}, {16}, {17}} -> White
    ]
   , x
   ];

ListDensityPlot[s
  , Mesh -> Automatic
  , ColorFunction -> cf
  , FrameLabel -> {Number, "Year"}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{{0, "Y1"}, {20, "Y2"}, {40, "Y3"}, {60, "Y4"}, {80,
        "Y5"}}, 
     None}, {{{1, "One"}, {10, "Two"}, {20, "Three"}, {30, 
       "Four"}, {40, "Five"}, {50, "Six"}}, None}}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Heat Map"
  , PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic], After]
  , PlotRange -> {-1, 1}] /. 
 x : (FrameTicks -> _) :> (x /. s_String :> Rotate[s, 45 Degree])
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

It is difficult to visually verify results with random numbers, so the following example is included.

```
data = Flatten[#, 1] &@
  Table[{x, y, Sin[x] Sin[y]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi], 
    0.1}]

GraphicsRow[
 ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> #, 
    PlotLegends -> {BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 180]}
    , ColorFunctionScaling -> True
    ] & /@ {"Rainbow", cf}
 ]
```

Comment: Many thanks! That worked fine.